# dotnet core: can't run unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit.net

I am developing an application using dotnet core.
When I try to run the unit tests, I receive the following message:

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Unable to communicate with test host process.
```

I already checked my .csproj files, I have uninstaled and instaled again dotnet core, tried to rebuild the projects, tried to restore the packages again, searched for code errors, but I have no clue of what is happening.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

The project that is facing the issue is available here: https://github.com/andremteixeira/Personal-Accounting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have created a stack overflow exception that unfortunately completely crashes the test host process..

The problem is:

1. Any operator is called
2. This calls `CheckNullity`
3. `CheckNullity` has a `a == null` comparison
4. This invokes the custom `bool operator == (Money a, Money b)`
5. Which forwards to `bool IsEquivalent(Money a, Money b)`
6. Which has a check for `a != null`
7. Which invokes the custom operator `bool operator != (Money a, Money b)`
8. Which has a check for `a == null`
9. This lands at 4. again

if I replace

```
if (a == null || b == null)
```

with

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(b, null))
```

in `CheckNullity` it breaks the cycle and all the tests run.

Comment: how did you figure it out?

Comment: `dotnet test -d diag.log` printed a stack overflow exception (sadly without stack trace) so I looked for places that could cause one..

Comment: wow. That would took a lot of experience with the language. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, Martin. When I came home today and tested your solution, it still didn't work. Can you help to figure it out? I see you have a very good expertise and can help me solve this. I would appreciate. :)

Comment: Its me again. I've found more places in my code with the same situation that generated the stack overflow and applied your suggestion. Now it works perfectly. Yay! :D